# How to recover tuleap aministration project

Tags: project, tuleap

I've deleted the Administration project on Tuleap. 
Therefore I lost the Admin menu on the upper right.
How can I recover the Administration project? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by executing the following script in MySQL Tuleap Database:

```
update groups set status = 'A' where group_id='1';

insert into user_group(user_id,group_id, admin_flags, bug_flags, forum_flags, project_flags, patch_flags, support_flags, file_flags, wiki_flags, svn_flags, news_flags) values(101, 1, 'A', 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2 );
```